# Adding content to list

Tags: python, list

I have the following code:

```
list = []
content = "1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1"
```

How do I add the content to the list?
Feels like a very silly question, but I don't manage.

UPDATE:
Thanks, the split-command did the work. Solved!

Comment: Please clarify. (a) Do you want to add the whole string as one element, or (b) do you want to split it and add the numbers as strings, or (c) do you want to split it and add the numbers as integers?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.append()`

```
list.append(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `content` is just a string, you can just `split` and turn it into a list.

`myList = content.split(",")`

Also, don't name your list `list`, because `list` is a reserved keyword in Python and will likely cause problems.

edit: it's not a reserved keyword, it's a reserved type as pointed out by inof in the comment below. Still bad practice to use it for a variable name.

Comment: `list` is *not* a reserved keyword (like `if` etc.). It’s a built-in type. You can rebind it if you want, e.g. `list = "Now it's a string!"`, but that’s probably not a good idea.

Comment: Oh, sorry! But yes, it's still bad practice to name a list as such.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to split the string and add the elements as integers (which makes the most sense), this will do it:

```
mylist = []
mylist += [int(i) for i in content.split(",")]
```

Note that it is not a good idea to name your list `list`, because that is already the name of the built-in type.

Of course, if the list is empty to begin with (according to your code), you can initialize it in one step without having to assign an empty list first:

```
mylist = [int(i) for i in content.split(",")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Few possible ways -

1. list of strings -

```
my_list = []
content = "1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1"

#if you want string.
my_list = content.split(',')
```

2. list of int

```
# if int(list comprehension)
my_list = [int(s) for s in content.split(',')]

# if int(via map)
my_list = list(map(int,content.split(',')))
```

Note -> 2nd case may throw an error if initial string contains contains non_numeric characters -
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'some_char'`